# How do I reenable opening jar files by double clicking on them?

Tags: nautilus, java

How can I make "double click to run" the default behaviour of a jar-file on Nautilus?
There is no "Open with OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime" on the "Open with" tab under Properties.

Comment: [Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1176985) on Launchpad

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try the following:

If you have **OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime** installed in your system, then you should have a file named **openjdk-7-java.desktop** in the folder */usr/share/applications/*

Check if you have the .desktop file.

1. Go to the terminal and type:

   `cd /usr/share/applications`

   `ls -l openjdk-7-java.desktop`
2. If the result is:

   `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 367 Oct 24 22:29 openjdk-7-java.desktop`
3. Then *(to associate OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime to the java files)* you can edit the file **defaults.list** also in the folder */usr/share/applications/* .
4. In the terminal type:

   `sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/defaults.list`
5. Search for **application/x-jar** and **application/x-java-archive** in the defualts.list, and change the .desktop file to the **openjdk-7-java.desktop** and save the changes.

[image: Screenshot of gedit /usr/share/applications/defaults.list]

Now the java files should be open with Open JDK 7 by default. To double-click and run, make sure the file has execute permissions.

You can set the permissions in the terminal with: `chmod 755 file.jar` or right click in the file, permissions tab and click in *"Allow executing file as a program"*

[image: File properties]

Finally double-click in the file to run it.

Hope this will helpful!

Regards.

Comment: This solved my problem too. For later readers of this topic, this is also working on 13.04.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work on 13.10, the defaults.list already has openjdk-7-java.desktop in there and the jar file I'm trying to run is already marked executable, and still jar files give the error about being blocked because it's not executable. Also checked and verified that the java binaries and all links through the chain to them are executable.