# Set OpenJDK as default application

Tags: 12.10, java, minecraft, openjdk

I'm trying to create a launcher for Minecraft, but in order to make a proper working launcher I need to have OpenJDK Java 7 set as the default application for opening the .jar file. Here's the problem: when I look at the Open With tab of its Properties window, there's no way to select OpenJDK. What do?

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be a better explanation, if you haven't already found it yourself.

Open a terminal window and type:

```
cd /usr/share/applications
```

Now follow [the Step #4 of this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/224480/62483) onward!

Answer (score 1):

All the file associations are stored in the file :

`/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`

create a `java.desktop` for java in `/usr/share/applications/`

see here for instructions : [link](http://linuxcritic.wordpress.com/2010/04/07/anatomy-of-a-desktop-file/)

change the line at the beginning of the file

`application/x-jar=java.desktop`

Comment: I don't think I fully understand. So I should enter into gedit:
`application/x-jar=java.desktop`
`Type=Application`
`Name=Java`
and what exactly should be in the Exec field?

Comment: exec=/usr/bin/java

Comment: Ok I did that and saved it as `/usr/share/applications/java.desktop`, now what? It doesn't appear to have done anything.