# How to add "open jdk7" to deffault open program list?

Tags: java, default-programs, openjdk

I want to open a .jar file, but "open jdk 7" is not in other applications list. How can I add "open jdk 7" to "other applications" list and then set it as default opener?

I have no such problem in ubuntu 12.04 but in 13.04 I can not set "open jdk 7" as default. I have to right click on .jar file and select open with "open jdk7" every time that is annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the answer: [How do I reenable opening jar files by double clicking on them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224463/how-do-i-reenable-opening-jar-files-by-double-clocking-on-them)

Check that answer.
In short, you have to edit the file `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` as root (`sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/defaults.list`, for example), 
search for the two lines that start with **application/x-jar** and **application/x-java-archive** and change the *.desktop* values of those lines to **openjdk-7-java.desktop**, if you have openjdk-7 installed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on .JAR file
2. Click "Open with..."
3. Click "Custom command line"
4. Type in the text field: `java -jar`
5. Click the checkbox "Set as default action for this file type"
6. Click "OK"

The .JAR should start now. From then on, you can just double click the .JAR to start it.