# How to open jar file using open JDK?

Tags: java, default, default-programs, openjdk

I installed "open jdk 7" on ubuntu 13.04, but not recognized in "other application" list to set as default. I need to open a ".jar" file with "open jdk7". Please help.

Comment: The executable you want to associate with is "java", not "openjdk". Is that in the list?

Comment: Hi Ash, thank you for answer.When I right click on ".jar" file and select "open with" the "oracle java runtime" and "open jdk" are in list but not in default. I want to set one of "java" or "open jdk" as default, but when I go >>> right click > properties > open with to set as default, none of "java" or "open jdk" are in list. Only "oracle java 7 web start" is in list.

Comment: I'm not sure, does this help: http://askubuntu.com/a/224480/121193 ?

Comment: @Ash thank you for answer, I used your posted link above and fixed my problem.

Answer (score 6):

**1.** **First** you need to have installed java. Can install from Software Center or by following command in terminal. (Open terminal with pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> ).

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless
```

**2.** **Right click on the .jar file and select `Open With Openjdk Java 6/7 Runtime`**

[image]

** If there is no `Open With Openjdk Java 6/7 Runtime` option in menu, then select `Open with` and then select `Openjdk Java 6/7 Runtime`

** If it is not even in the `Open with` then select `Other Aplication...` and select `Openjdk Java 6/7 Runtime`

[image]

[image]

** If it is even not found here, then select `Show other apllications` Button. Here you can select `Openjdk Java 6/7 Runtime`

[image]

** If it is not even in `Show other apllications` list, you need to done something in *Terminal*

**i.**  Open terminal with pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> .

**ii.**  Paste this in terminal prompt and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
gksudo gedit '/usr/share/applications/openjdk-7-java.desktop'
```

**iii.**  In the resulting gedit document, Change the `NoDisplay=true` line to `NoDisplay=false`: then save the file and close it.

[image]

**iv.**  Then you will able to find `Openjdk Java 6/7 Runtime` in any of the above `Open with` menu.

**3.**  **Another method is to create a Desktop icon to launch this .jar file application. To do that :**

**i.**  In terminal run `gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/[NAME OF THE APPLICATION].desktop`

** Replace the `[NAME OF THE APPLICATION]` with .jar file name.

**iI.**  Add the following lines to the resulting empty gedit. Replace the text in `[ ]` with appropriate. Then save it and close.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=[APPLICATION NAME]
Comment=[WHAT EVER]
Exec=java -jar [DIRECTORY OF THE FILE]/[FILE NAME.JAR] %F
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=/usr/share/icons/gnome/256x256/apps/[ANY ICON YOU LIKE IN THIS FOLDER]
NoDisplay=false
MimeType=applications/php
```

**iii.**  You will able to find the icon for this application in Dash. You can open the `.jar` file application by click on it.

Comment: For me, run with JRE option (steps until "If it is not even in Show other apllications list") is there only for JRE 6, not for JRE 7.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the previous answers work, you can try this:

[How do I reenable opening jar files by double clicking on them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224463/how-do-i-reenable-opening-jar-files-by-double-clicking-on-them)

but if you are using Ubuntu 14.04, you must make a small change in step 1 and 5.

In ubuntu 14.04, the application's name is `openjdk-7-policytool.desktop` and not `openjdk-7-java.desktop`.

So, make the changes like this:

Step 1 :

```
cd /usr/share/applications
ls -l openjdk-7-policytool.desktop
```

Step 5.

```
application/x-jar=openjdk-7-policytool.desktop
application/x-java-archive=openjdk-7-policytool.desktop
```

Then reboot and you are done.
Now the java files should be open with Open JDK 7 by default.

Note: To double-click and run, make sure the file has execute permissions.

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to flag this question as a duplicate of the other (with the [flag] button below this one). If you think the cited answer is outdated or needs other improvements, please suggest an edit to it and don't create a new answer.