# how to open technicLauncher.jar in ubuntu

Tags: jar

I am completely new to ubuntu. Just got it installed on my laptop yesterday as the windows program crashed and this is the only thing we could get to work. i have downloaded techniclauncher on the computer and it saves it as a .jar file. I have no idea how to get it opened/downloaded/launched (whatever the correct word is) so that we can actually play the game. Can someone please help me learn how to do this. Again I am completely new and do not understand all the ubuntu terminology but i am computer literate and can generally be told specifics and get it done. thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

To open .jar file you need to have installed Java. Then you need to open .jar file with java. ( Change the `Open With ..` option in right click menu to the Java package you have installed.)

If you havent installed Java, you can installed by following :

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> : You will get the Terminal with prompt. (Like CMD in Win)

Then, in the prompt Copy & Paste this line. Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jdk
```

You should be online in internet while doing this.

Comment: i haven't installed java but i'm not getting what you mean by install with "sudo ...." am i suppose to type that in somewhere and it will install it, if so where do i put it and do i type it exactly the way it shows with spaces and all? again i am not at all familiar with the process but i appreciate any help i can get

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: ok I did that and this is what the end result was   laurie@laurie-Satellite-L655:~$   what do i need to do to open java and launch techniclauncher....sorry to sound so illiterate but i'm just not used to this so glad for the help though  i'm guess java is there but i don't know where to find it

Comment: did you searched in right click menu ?

Comment: no where do i need to be to right click to search...on the desktop, in dash home, home folder or where

Comment: Please follow [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/381093/164718) answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Java 8 (Java 10 and 11 are too new, from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/technicplatform/comments/9oip5t/technic_launcher_wont_start_on_linux_and_i_dont/ecxg3qg/)) with `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk`
2. Ensure `java -version` shows 1.8. If not use update-alternatives with `sudo update-alternatives --config java`
3. Run jar file with `java -jar TechnicLauncher.jar`